# Highcharts in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I don't want the name of series displayed inside of the highchart in angularjs. Can anyone tell me the solution for this?

Even if I give

```
series : [{
       name:'',
       data:somedata 
}]
```

It displays as "series1".

Answer (score 0):

You can mention option as `showInLegend: false` inside your series option.

**CODE**

```
series : [{
       data:somedata,
       showInLegend: false
}]
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-showinlegend/)

Hope this would help you. Thanks.